# I would like to know how to map dictionary with list of value to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-ndarray

I would like to make this

| City |
| --- |
| Seoul |
| Busan |
| Deagu |
| Seoul |
| Seoul |
| Busan |

into this which now has `latitude` and `longtitue`

| City | Latitude | Logitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Seoul | 127 | 50 |
| Busan | 128 | 51 |
| Daegu | 129 | 52 |
| Seoul | 127 | 50 |
| Seoul | 127 | 50 |
| Busan | 128 | 51 |

I tried this using code below

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {"Seoul":[127,50],
         "Busan":[128,51],
         "Daegu":[129,52]}

data = {'City':['Seoul', 'Busan', 'Daegu', 'Seoul','Seoul','Busan']}

test1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

for city, list1 in dict1.items():
    print(city," ", list1[0],list1[1])

for num, city, list1 in zip(range(7),dict1.items()):
    if test1.loc[:,"City"] == city:
        test1.loc["Latitude"] = list1[0]
        test1.loc["Longitude"] = list1[1]
```

But it returned error for not having enough elements for `for loop`
and need more efficient way better than iterating for length of list
Have a great day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1, orient='index', columns=['Latitude','Longitude'])
test1 = test1.join(df1, on='City')
print (test1)
    City  Latitude  Longitude
0  Seoul       127         50
1  Busan       128         51
2  Daegu       129         52
3  Seoul       127         50
4  Seoul       127         50
5  Busan       128         51
```

Comment: Nice answer man! Had to go with other solutions haha, other wise might of chose yours.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know ```join```!!! Looks like i can use it for many situations.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following one-liner:

```
print(pd.DataFrame([[k] + v for k, v in dict1.items()], columns=['City', 'Latitude', 'Longitude']).set_index('City').loc[data['City']].reset_index())
```

Or as @jezrael mentioned below, you could also do unpacking with:

```
print(pd.DataFrame([(k, *v) for k, v in dict1.items()], columns=['City', 'Latitude', 'Longitude']).set_index('City').loc[data['City']].reset_index())
```

Output:

```
    City  Latitude  Longitude
0  Seoul       127         50
1  Busan       128         51
2  Daegu       129         52
3  Seoul       127         50
4  Seoul       127         50
5  Busan       128         51
```

Comment: Or `print(pd.DataFrame([(k, *v) for k, v in dict1.items()], columns=['City', 'Latitude', 'Longitude']))`

Comment: @jezrael Oh thanks for that suggestion, edited my answer now

Comment: Thank you for answering! But for the detail about ```[k]``` why does it need square brackets? Isn't it supposed to be ```City``` columns?

Comment: @이가원 Oh, `k` is the key which is a single value such as `Seoul` so `Seoul + [127, 50]` would give an error, so it has to be `[Seoul] + [127, 50]` to work.

Comment: So in order to use the plus operator, both need to be kind of list(or pointer as @jezrael suggest?